# Stationarity of independent variables in ARIMAX

Tags: arima, stationarity

I am running an ARIMA model with exogenous variables. Do all my exogenous variables have to be stationary or is it okay if one of my exogenous variable is non-stationary?

Comment: Just in case: are you using R and `arima` or `auto.arima`? If so, you are fitting regression with ARMA errors rather than ARIMAX, see Rob J. Hyndman's blog post ["The ARIMAX model muddle"](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/). Other than that, could you give an example of your model? (It could narrow down the question and make it easier to answer rather than considering all possible cases.)